# Angular inline condition

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have the following row in my jade file

```
img(src="{{ item.product.image1.match('http') ? item.product.image1 : 'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{_awsbucket}item.product.image1 }}'", alt='{{item.product.productNumber}}')
```

As you can see, I want to add http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{bucket} as src when the URL does not contain 'http'. 
This condition fails, (angular error), but I can't see any errors. Maybe someone have an idea?

> angular.js:12477Error: [$parse:lexerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=…ttp%3A%2F%2Fs3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2F***bucket***item.product.image1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is here:

```
'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{_awsbucket}item.product.image1 }}'"
```

you have placed a quote in the wrong place. replace it with:

```
'http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{_awsbucket}item.product.image1'}}"
```

Comment: Ahhh. You found it! Thanks! Changed the quote little bit, show it will show the image instead of the plain text 'item.product.image1' 

http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{_awsbucket}'+ item.product.image1}}"

Comment: So you resolved your issue? if you need no further assistance, close the question by accepting the answer (so we don't pollute unresolved questions on SO).

Comment: Hi, yeah accepted now. A little minute ago, I was to fast to accepted the answer :)